# Use a Message with a placeholder in jsp

Tags: jsp, message

I can output messages on my JSP page like this:

```
    <fmt:message key="conditions.text" var="text"  />
    ${text}
```

but how can i fill the placeholders when the mesage looks like that

```
Hello {0}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was

```
    <fmt:message key="conditions.text" var="text">
        <fmt:param value="NAME"/>
    </fmt:message>
```